# Is it possible to pop to the n - 2 or n - 3 view?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa

I know that it's easy to pop to the previous `viewController` with:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Is it possible however, to pop, *not to the previous view*, but the n - 2 or n - 3 view?

Comment: You can pop by, [self.navigationController popToViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but it must be done differently, first grab the current stack of viewcontrollers from the navigation controller:

```
NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [self.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
```

In the code you see that I've made the array mutable, now you can manipulate the array:

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(2, 2);
[viewControllers removeObjectsInRange:range];
```

Here I remove 2 view controller from position 2, of course there are many more ways to remove/add controller from the array.

Then Just assign the new array to the navigationController:

```
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:YES];
```